# Mongo Aggregate find element in array based on match/sort/slice/group query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write a pipeline query on the following

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "createdDate" : "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
    "visits" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "2018-02-01 00:00:00",
            "type" : "A",
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2018-03-01 00:00:00",
            "type" : "B",
        }]
    "user" : "Alpha"
},

{
    "_id" : 1,
    "createdDate" : "2018-01-15 00:00:00",
    "visits" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "2018-02-01 00:00:00",
            "type" : "B",
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2018-04-08 00:00:00",
            "type" : "A",
        }]
    "user" : "Alpha"
}
```

I want to

- Group by user
- Get No of Records
- Basis a date filter
- latest type to be selected basis the same date filter

Example:

date between 2018-01-01 and 2018-02-02

Desired Output

```
{_id:"Alpha",
type: {"A":1, "B":1},
count : 2}
```

date between 2018-01-01 and 2018-03-02

Desired Output

```
{_id:"Alpha",
type: {"A":0, "B":2},
count : 2}
```

Here is where i have got so far

```
{$match:{ "createdDate":{   "$gte":"2018-01-01 00:00:00",
                            "$lte":"2018-02-02 23:59:59"}     
        }
},
{$unwind:"$visits"},
{$match:{   "visits.date":{ "$gte":"2018-01-01 00:00:00",
                            "$lte":"2018-02-02 23:59:59"}
          }
},
{$project:{_id:1, "visit_type":"$visits.type", "visit_date":"$visits.date"}},
{ $group : {  _id         : "$_id",
              "visits"    :    { "$push": { 
                                    "date": "$visit_date",
                                    "type": "$visit_type"                                        
                                }
                                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

Added two groups one group each for count by type and other for count by user.

```
[
  {"$match":{"createdDate":{"$gte":"2018-01-01 00:00:00","$lte":"2018-03-02 23:59:59"}}},
  {"$unwind":"$visits"},
  {"$match":{"visits.date":{"$gte":"2018-01-01 00:00:00","$lte":"2018-03-02 23:59:59"}}},
  {"$sort":{"visits.date":-1}},
  {"$group":{"_id":{"_id":"$_id","user":"$user"},"latestvisit":{"$first":"$visits"}}},
  {"$group":{"_id":{"user":"$_id.user","type":"$latestvisit.type"},"visits":{"$sum":1}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.user",
    "type":{"$push":{"type":"$_id.type","visits":"$visits"}},
    "count":{"$sum":"$visits"}
  }}
]
```

Comment: One thing missing here is that we need to consider latest visit from the array as per the date range

Comment: Can you update the expected json to show what you mean by latest visit ?

Comment: As i have indicated in my question. the result changes with the two different date queries. type: {"A":1, "B":1} vs type: {"A":0, "B":2},

Comment: how is  {"A":0, "B":2} but not {"A":1, "B":2} for date range 2018-01-01 and 2018-03-02 ?

Comment: latest of visits in first document for date range 2018-01-01 and 2018-02-02 would be "type" : "A" as the second in array is out of date range. if Date range is changed to 2018-01-01 and 2018-03-02, then latest would be "type" : B. This is how the count can change

Comment: oh okay. I think I got it. Can you take a look at the updated answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166912/discussion-between-shadab-tughlaq-and-veeram).

Comment: I implemented this on the live db as well. Works as expected. THANKS :-)